# how to clear a blob column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a file in a table, how may i "set empty" some file (in blob) ?

ty all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`EMPTY_BLOB()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions064.htm#SQLRF00636):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    blob_column = EMPTY_BLOB()
WHERE  id          = your_id;
```